# Discrete Mathematics -Propositional Logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How to get

```
B↔C from B∧C . Using derivation method i.e Step by Step .


My attempt :
            i) B∧C Rule P 
            ii)B Rule T (i) Simplification B∧C ⇒ B
            iii)C Rule T (i) Simplification B∧C ⇒ C
```

I'm stuck here ..

Comment: What are the rules you are using?

Comment: @BruceZheng any one can be used ( direct ,C.P ,Contradiction , indirect)

Comment: I'm not familiar with them being called Rule P, Rule T, etc. But $B \Leftrightarrow C$ follows from ii and iii by definition.

Comment: @BruceZheng How to prove it using the method above. Rule P is Rule Premises and Rule T is the rule tautology

Comment: I don't know because I need to know what your rules are called!

Comment: No need . Just say how did you get B⇔C from ii and iii is there any tautological implication or equivalences .

Answer (score 3):

**HINT** (first 3 lines):

1. Suppose $B\land C$
2. Suppose $B$
3. $C$  (from 1)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have a natural deduction system in mind:

**Goal**: Derive $B \leftrightarrow C$ from the set of premises $\{B \wedge C\}$, in symbols:

> $B \wedge C \vdash B \leftrightarrow C.$

Recall that for deriving a biconditional $\phi \leftrightarrow \psi$ we first have to show that a conditional holds in both sides,

> $\vdash \phi \rightarrow \psi$ and $\vdash \psi \rightarrow \phi.$

Hence, our new goal is derive both $B \rightarrow C$ and $C \rightarrow B$. Let's first obtain the former.

Since we want to obtain a conditional $B \rightarrow C$, we (i) assume the antecedent $B$ as a hypothesis, (ii) derive the consequent under this assumption, (iii) use the [conditional introduction rule](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formal_Logic/Sentential_Logic/Subderivations_and_Discharge_Rules#The_Conditional_Introduction_rule) to conclude that $B$ implies $C$:

> > 1. $B$, H
> > 2. $B \wedge C$, P
> > 3. $C$, 2 $\land$E (Rule called Conjunction Elimination)
>
> 4. $B \to C$, 1-3 $\to$I (Conditional Introduction)

Now we do the same to obtain $C \to B$

> > 5. $C$, H
> > 6. $B \wedge C$, P
> > 7. $B$, 6 $\land$E (Conjunction Elimination)
>
> 8. $C \to B$, 5-7 $\to$I (Conditional Introduction)

and we use lines 4 and 8 to get a biconditional:

> 9. $C \leftrightarrow B$, 4, 8 $\leftrightarrow$I (Rule called Biconditional Introduction)

Now let's put all the steps together:

> > 1. $B$, H
> > 2. $B \wedge C$, P
> > 3. $C$, 2 $\land$E
>
> 4. $B \to C$, 1-3 $\to$I
>
> > 5. $C$, H
> > 6. $B \wedge C$, P
> > 7. $B$, 6 $\land$E
>
> 8. $C \to B$, 5-7 $\to$I
> 9. $C \leftrightarrow B$, 4, 8 $\leftrightarrow$I

Did you get the idea?

Comment: got the idea ... Thanks

Comment: Did you find my hint helpful?

Comment: @DanChristensen It's simply what i wrote in my question . If you are able to answer showing all the steps it would be helpful .

Answer (score -2):

I use Lukasiewicz/Polish notation and condensed detachment.  The axioms I will use are:

1. CpCqp.
2. CKpqp.
3. CKpqq.
4. CCpqCCqpEpq.

Here we go:

```
assumption 5 Kbc.
D2.5       6 b.
D1.6       7 Cqb.
D3.5       8 c.
D1.8       9 Cqc.
D4.9      10 CCcqEqc.
D10.7     11 Ebc.
```